# Asia/Tehran timezone problem +0430 in PHP:7.3.1-fpm docker

Tags: php, docker, timezone

`environment: TZ: Asia/Tehran`

I was added TZ to my php fpm as enviroment, when i run `date` in container bash, the result is +0430 !

I can't to upgrade my php version

It should return +0330 , Im certain the Asia/Tehran is +0330 not +0430

I did try the fill the TZ as environment but nothing happen

- Docker image: php:7.3.1-fpm

Comment: PHP 7.3.1 was released in January 2019... so you've got no changes to the time zone database that occurred after that. I would say that if you can't update to a newer version of PHP, you've got bigger problems than just time zone issues though - I'd be willing to bet that in the last 4 1/2 years, there have been relevant security fixes. So you *could* focus on whether there's some way of updating the time zone database without updating PHP - or you could put all your effort into being able to update PHP, knowing there are multiple benefits in doing so.

Comment: (Looking at https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/NEWS, the Asia/Tehran zone changes in release 2022b, in August 2022.)

Comment: Thanks ! I find out should use pecl for updating timezonedb

Comment: One _can_ use PECL for updating timezonedb, or one can just stay current with PHP updates, which always include the latest timezonedb available at time of release.